# Why is accessing LocalEntries in Cache slower on larger partitions?

Tags: performance, ignite

We are testing performance of our system in Apache Ignite.  To isolate a performance issue we are testing on a single node.  We have created 10 parts and are varying the size of the parts.  A part in our case is an ArrayList of records, so we have 100 records, 1000, 10000 etc.

The issue is that when we try to iterate through the local entries the performance goes down as the *value* increases in size.  **Note, this is iterating through the iterator, not traversing the `ArrayList` of records.**  This is not the expected behavior.  In contrast, for a local iterator/collection iterating through the values does not (and should not) decrease in performance.

```
    IgniteCallable<Map<String,Long>> closure = () -> {
        Map<String,Long> results = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        // Get all the local entries for this node
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        Iterable<Entry<Long, List<Object>>> localEntries = cache.localEntries(CachePeekMode.PRIMARY);
        results.put("getCache",System.nanoTime() - startTime);


        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        List<Entry<Long, List<Object>>> entries = new LinkedList();
        for(Entry<Long, List<Object>> entry : localEntries){
            entries.add(entry);
        }
        List<List<Object>> iteratedList = new LinkedList();
        // THIS is the part that takes like 90% of the time
        results.put("traverseIterator",System.nanoTime()-startTime);


        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        for(Entry<Long, List<Object>> entry : entries){
            iteratedList.add(entry.getValue());
        }
        results.put("getValues",System.nanoTime()-startTime);

        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        int prtCnt = 0;
        int totalCnt = 0;
        for(List<Object> list : iteratedList){
            int i = 0;
            for(Object mr: list){
                i++;
            }
            prtCnt++;
            totalCnt += i;
        }
        results.put("traverseSet",System.nanoTime()-startTime);

        results.put("checksum",new Long(totalCnt));
        return results;
    };
```

Initially we thought it was cluster overhead or something for co-ordinating since this iterator is part of a cluster, but that doesn't make sense if the performance is dependent on the size of the value.  It is almost behaving as if it is deserializing the value, however (as far as I know) we have everything on-heap so there shouldn't be that overhead.  Can anyone see why iterating and getting the cache's values is taking so long?

Here is my cache configuration:

```
    <property name="cacheConfiguration">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
            <!-- Set a cache name. -->
            <property name="name" value="monthly" />
            <property name="rebalanceMode" value="ASYNC" />
            <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED" />
            <property name="atomicityMode" value="ATOMIC"/>
            <property name="backups" value="1" />
            <property name="memoryMode" value="ONHEAP_TIERED" />
            <property name="offHeapMaxMemory" value="0" />
            <property name="swapEnabled" value="false" />
            <property name="cacheStoreFactory">
                <bean class="javax.cache.configuration.FactoryBuilder" factory-method="factoryOf">
                    <constructor-arg value="com.ignite.datastore.ListDataStore" />
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="readThrough" value="true" />
            <property name="writeThrough" value="true" />
            <property name="copyOnRead" value="false" />
        </bean>
    </property>
```

Answer (score 2):

With `copyOnRead=false` deserialization should not happen when you read data locally (which is always the case with only one node). If you see a different behavior in your particular case, than it can be a bug. I would recommend you to create a test and give to the Ignite community [1]. Someone there will take a look and provide feedback.

[1] http://ignite.apache.org/community/resources.html#mail-lists

Comment: Ok, will create a standalone test case tomorrow.  Thanks